# How to get selected value from dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am binding dropdownlist from model, but am unable to get the selected value from the dropdownlist, it shows error:

> > The value '1' is invalid , while submitting the form

### Model code

```
[Display(Name="User Type")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select user type")]
public List<SelectListItem> usertype { get; set; }
```

### View code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.usertype, Model.usertype, new {  @class="form-control input-lg"})
```

### Controller code

```
//controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Register register,FormCollection form)
{
}
```

### To populate dropdownlist

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model=new Register();
    List<string> stState = new List<string>();
    List<SelectListItem> selectListItemStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
    selectListItemStates.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = string.Empty, Text = "Select State" });
    selectListItemStates.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Mentor" });
    selectListItemStates.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Employee" });
    selectListItemStates.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value ="1", Text = "Finance" });


    model.usertype = selectListItemStates.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Each SelectListItem has a value of 1? That's not right...

Comment: @Kjata: yup that's just for demo.i am aware of that, i did that purposely .

Comment: The point is that your code examples should be as accurate as possible and ideally not confusing to the reader. Please update.

Comment: okay ,lemme break it down . 
i want to add dropdownlist of strongly type , with validations , and also want to get selected value from the dropdownlist .
i am able to do the first 2 things , but unable to get the selected value,
while posting page it says ,"The value '1' is invalid"

Comment: Just edit your question to be clearer, don't try to clarify in comments.

Comment: i've posted the same .

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a property in Model  for SelectedValue which can be `int` most probably.

Currently you are binding `DropDownListFor` with `SelectList` which is not right, `DropDownListFor` will post single value which is selected, which is normally integer :

```
    public List<SelectListItem> usertype { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="User Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select user type")]
    public int UserType { get; set; }
```

and in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.UserType,Model.usertype, new {  @class="form-control input-lg"}
```

Comment: i tried this thing , but using that dropdownlist is not validating.

Comment: Have you added data annotation on it?

Comment: okay ,lemme break it down . i want to add dropdownlist of strongly type , with validations , and also want to get selected value from the dropdownlist . i am able to do the first 2 things , but unable to get the selected value, while posting page it says ,"The value '1' is invalid"

Comment: It is saying because you are posting `List` as selected value which is not right

Comment: okay, but then how to fetch the selected value.
According to your code , you are binding UserType with dropdownlistfor, but then how it will get selected value, i don't understand that..

Comment: Have you seen that I added a `int` property in Model , I will post working fiddle when I log on my system , currently on mobile

Comment: yup i tried that code , it's not working. 
okay please post the working fiddle .